# How to interpolate ruby and coffee script variable in `coffee.erb` file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I want to use a function like this in `app/assets/javascripts/foo.js.coffee.erb` file.

loadImage = (size="normal") ->
  imgName = "<%= asset_path('load-#{size}.gif') %>"

This code doesn't work, because coffee script variable is not interpolated.
If I write `'<%= asset_path("load-#{size}.gif") %>'`, then `#{size}` is recognized ruby variable and needless to say, it doesn't work neither.

How can I write a code like this?

Comment: Coffeescript variables and ruby variables don't mix and match. Howver, just from your example, it would seem that you should be able to just do `"<%= asset_path('load-normal.gif') %>"`.

Comment: I can call this function `loadImage()` and `loadImage('small')`. If there is no way to mix two of them, I'll write it without variables as you wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will search for the same:

You can use `coffee_script_tag` for it.

```
loadImage = (size="normal") -> imgName = "<%= asset_path('load-#{coffee_script_tag(size)}.gif') %>"
```

and that should work.

It looks weird, so I suppose you would not need this until you are doing something wrong. At least one should remember that the erb-expression will be evaluated once, with the value when the page is rendered.